# Where can I find the Linux logo in the Linux kernel source tree?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I use stable kernel of 4.19.78 version and I want to find C-array with binary data of penguin. It is displayed when system is booted. 
Where do I need to search the one?

I have found only the declarations of some logos in `include/linux/linux_logo.h` file:

```
extern const struct linux_logo logo_linux_mono;
extern const struct linux_logo logo_linux_vga16;
extern const struct linux_logo logo_linux_clut224;
extern const struct linux_logo logo_dec_clut224;
extern const struct linux_logo logo_mac_clut224;
extern const struct linux_logo logo_parisc_clut224;
extern const struct linux_logo logo_sgi_clut224;
extern const struct linux_logo logo_sun_clut224;
extern const struct linux_logo logo_superh_mono;
extern const struct linux_logo logo_superh_vga16;
extern const struct linux_logo logo_superh_clut224;
extern const struct linux_logo logo_spe_clut224;
```

This variables are used in `drivers/video/logo/logo.c` file, but I can't find C-array with data.

Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/video/logo and https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/video/logo/logo.c#L26 and https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/video/logo/Makefile#L40 and https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/scripts/pnmtologo.c#L3

Comment: The logo are in the same directory. The `scripts/pnmtologo` has the conversion routine, as you see in the Makefile in the logo directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where can I find the Linux logo in the Linux kernel source tree?

The logos are in bmp files located in [drivers/video/logo](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/video/logo).

The bmp files are converted by [drivers/video/logo/makefile](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/video/logo/Makefile#L40) with the usage of [pnmtologo](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/scripts/pnmtologo.c#L3) script to C source files with proper [variable of type `struct linux_logo`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/scripts/pnmtologo.c#L254) definition with the logo file contents. Then this generated c file is compiled and linked with the kernel.